# how can i use a foreach on a foreach php

Tags: php, curl, foreach

hi guys i have this script but obviously im not using foreach right i was wondering is there anyway i could combine these two requests to works as one

```
$url = "http://api.website.com/1.0/country?source=ballsche&programid=5380&campaignid=100000";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$array = json_decode($rawdata,true);
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $country = $obj['country'];
    $countrycode = $obj['countryCode'];

}
foreach($countrycode as $did) {
    $wgurl = "http://api.website.com/1.0/city?source=ballsche&programid=5380&campaignid=100000&country-code=$did";
    $wgch = curl_init();
    $wgtimeout = 0;
    curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_URL, $wgurl);
    curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $wgtimeout);
    $wgrawdata = curl_exec($wgch);
    curl_close($wgch);
    $wgarray = json_decode($wgrawdata,true);
}
foreach($wgarray as $wgobj) {
    $city = $wgobj['city'];
    $citycode = $wgobj['cityCode'];
    if($city){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `pt_city` (city, citycode) VALUES ('$city', '$citycode')";
        database_queryModify($sql,$result);
        }else{
        echo "dint work";
    }

}
```

there must be an easy way to do this im guesing creating another array from the data but i cant quite get it right i keep getting errors ive tried this and a few other things my problem is i need to cycle trough county codes and make requests from the code there a 150 requests i need to cycle trough to get all the city information and for each request i need to decode the json thats coming back and insert it into my city table

Comment: -1 For code not even following the basic laws of indentation.

Comment: what a prune haven't you ever heard if you cant say anything positive....

Comment: Dominic, I suggest you edit your question in a manner which will make it readable. Currently, it seems like a long meaningless sentence, which makes it difficult to understand what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put foreach inside each other like this

```
$url = "http://api.website.com/1.0/country?source=ballsche&programid=5380&campaignid=100000";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$array = json_decode($rawdata,true);
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $country = $obj['country'];
    $countrycode = $obj['countryCode'];

    foreach($countrycode as $did) {
        $wgurl = "http://api.website.com/1.0/city?source=ballsche&programid=5380&campaignid=100000&country-code=$did";
        $wgch = curl_init();
        $wgtimeout = 0;
        curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_URL, $wgurl);
        curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($wgch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $wgtimeout);
        $wgrawdata = curl_exec($wgch);
        curl_close($wgch);
        $wgarray = json_decode($wgrawdata,true);

        foreach($wgarray as $wgobj) {
            $city = $wgobj['city'];
            $citycode = $wgobj['cityCode'];
            if($city){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `pt_city` (city, citycode) VALUES ('$city', '$citycode')";
                database_queryModify($sql,$result);
            } else {
                echo "dint work";
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: that was the first thing i tried and i allways get an invalid argument supplied to foreach